# xslt 1.0 - transform nodes before specific element into other element

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

i have following Input:

```
<p>
    XYZZ
    <nl/>
    DEF
    <process>gggg</process>
    KKK
    <nl/>
    JKLK
    <nl/>
    QQQQ
</p>
```

I need each node seprated by element `<nl/>` to be output in element `<title>`:

```
<p>      
    <title>XYZZ</title>  
    <title>
        DEF<process>gggg</process>KKK  
    </title>  
    <title>JKLK</title>  
    <title>QQQQ</title>  
</p>
```

`
Please suggest me the way to get the specified output.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution that is also most efficient. I have carefully explained all steps in this solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key  name="kFollowing" match="/*/node()[not(self::nl)]"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::nl[1])"/>

 <xsl:key  name="kPreceding" match="/*/node()[not(self::nl)]"
  use="generate-id(following-sibling::nl[1])"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|nl"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="nl" name="groupFollowing">
      <title>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kFollowing',generate-id())"/>
      </title>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="nl[1]">
     <title>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kPreceding',generate-id())"/>
     </title>
     <xsl:call-template name="groupFollowing"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<p>
       XYZZ
       <nl/>
       DEF
       <process> gggg </process>
       KKK
       <nl/>
       JKLK
       <nl/>
       QQQQ
</p>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<p>
   <title>
       XYZZ
       </title>
   <title>
       DEF
       <process> gggg </process>
       KKK
       </title>
   <title>
       JKLK
       </title>
   <title>
       QQQQ
</title>
</p>
```

**Do note**:

1. **The identity rule is used** to copy nodes "as-is".
2. **There are specific templates** matching the top element, the first `nl` child of the top element and any `nl` child of the top element.
3. **Two keys are defined that select all non-`nl` nodes** that immediately-precede an `nl` element and all nodes that immediately-follow an `nl` element.
4. **An `nl` element is replaced by a `title` element** and all immediately-following non-`nl` nodes are processed and the result is put into this `title` element.
5. **For the first (child of its parent) `nl` element there is an initial step** in which a `title` element is added and all immediately-preceding non-`nl` nodes are processed and the result is put into this `title` element. Then the processing in step 4. above is performed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dimitre.. :) It worked very well for me. It also has cleared me the concept of using key, generate ID function. :-)

Comment: +1 Good answer. You could also use one key and an empty key value for first group. But this was more clear, truly.